# p4 sync as different user

Tags: perforce

How do you p4 sync as another user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the username (and even the password) via environment variables:

`P4USER=foo P4PASSWD=bar p4 sync`

also, have a look at `p4 help environment`

Answer (score 2):

These options can also be passed on the command line:

```
p4 -uUSER -PPASSWORD sync ...
```

Take a look at "p4 help usage" for details. It shows the arguments that all commands accept.